# How can I solve this 'key' warning?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Below is the error in my browser console:

```
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.
ExpenseList@http://localhost:3000/main.cfec1fef7369377b9a13.hot-update.js:29:7
div
Card@http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:2973:19
div
Expenses@http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:1482:97
div
App@http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:296:89
```

I believe it is referring me to the ExpenseList class. Below is the class:

```
import React from "react";
 
import ExpenseItem from "./ExpenseItem";
import './ExpensesList.css';
 
const ExpenseList = props => {
 
    if (props.expenses.length > 0) {
      
      return props.expenses.map((expense) => (
        <ul className="expenses-list">
          <ExpenseItem
            key={expense.id}
            title={expense.title}
            amount={expense.amount}
            date={expense.date}
          />
        </ul>
      ));
    }
 
    return <h2 className="expenses-list__fallback">Found No Expenses</h2>;
 
 
}
 
export default ExpenseList;
```

I cannot seem to find where the problem is, as I have already put the key.

Comment: add `key` on the `ul` element. Remove it from the `ExpenseItem` component - key is needed on the outermost element that is rendered inside a loop.

Comment: Put a key on the `ul`. https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html --- You probably didn't mean to loop over the `ul`, try putting the loop inside the `ul`?

Comment: Put a key on the `ul`

Comment: Put a key on the `ul` element

Answer (score 6):

```
const ExpenseList = props => {
 
    if (props.expenses.length > 0) {
      return <ul className="expenses-list">
      {props.expenses.map((expense) => (
          <ExpenseItem
            key={expense.id}
            title={expense.title}
            amount={expense.amount}
            date={expense.date}
          />
      ))}
      </ul>
    }
    return <h2 className="expenses-list__fallback">Found No Expenses</h2>;
}
```

Many people in comment say put a key in `ul`, but I think you should re-format like this.

Comment: While I agree with `but I think you should re-format like this.` an explanation of why the warning is shown, and why reformatting it that way is likely what the OP wants would help others. Especially if there are so many suggestions to place a key on `ul`.

Comment: @t.niese as a non-English native speaker, It is hard to explain something very well. I believe OP can understand just seeing the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add key for *ul* element, not *ExpenseItem*.

```
return props.expenses.map((expense) => (
    <ul key = {expense.id} className="expenses-list">
      <ExpenseItem
        title={expense.title}
        amount={expense.amount}
        date={expense.date}
      />
    </ul>
  ));
```

or loop to only *ExpenseItem*, not *ul* element.

```
return <ul className="expenses-list">
     props.expenses.map((expense) => (
      <ExpenseItem
        key = {expense.id}
        title={expense.title}
        amount={expense.amount}
        date={expense.date}
      />
     ));
    </ul>
```

Comment: I believe we need to help react detect unique item from list of items. So adding key to ExpenseItem makes sense

Comment: `Add key for ul element` That would silent the warning, but it is probably not the correct way to solve it, at least not from the perspective of semantics.